# Matlab: passing number to title

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to do anotation in matlab plot in a loop. 
In particular, I have

`num=[2 20 50 60 70]`

and I want to do

```
figure; hold on; 
plot(1:20,x^2);
for i=1:length(num)
text(i,2,'num is {num(i)}','FontSize',10)
```

However, when I do `num is {num(i)}` it doesn't give me this in the matlab plot. How do I pass the argument onto the plot?

Comment: Note that I changed the 'FrontSize' property in your code (which is probably a typo) to 'FontSize'.

Comment: so did any answer below helped you solve your problem? If so please accept the one that help you the most. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need:

```
text(i,2,['num is ' num2str(num(i))],'FontSize',10)
```

Comment: You also need an `end` for your `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Or as an alternative using [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html?refresh=true). You can play with the format of the output as well.

```
text(i,2,sprintf('num is %d',num(i)),'FontSize',10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the curly braces "{}". MATLAB does not interpret text inside curly braces as a variable name, as PHP do!

Try this:

```
x = 1:5;
y = x.^2;
figure
plot(x, y);
for i=1:length(x)
pointLabel = ['P(' num2str(x(i)) ', ' num2str(y(i)) ')'];
text(x(i), y(i), pointLabel, 'FontSize', 10);
end
```